# Using '=' versus clone() in Java

Tags: java, reference, clone, shallow-copy

I'm working on some code and trying to figure out how to copy an object reference to another object. I keep seeing the clone() method used, but I've read it's flawed and the class I'm wanting to copy is already implementing serializable. So one question I have is about the difference between using '=' and the clone method - My understanding is that both of these are shallow copies so they should work the same, but if that's true, then what is the benefit of having a method for this?

The code I'm working on has 2 arrays of objects - both the same type of object, all objects in both arrays are initially null, and I assign the values of array B to equal array A.
As the code progresses objects in array A are initialized and values are assigned to the variables of the objects in array A.
At the end of the code though, all objects in array B are still null.

Do I have the concept wrong here?
If the concept isn't wrong I assume it's just something I'm overlooking in my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is comparing apples to oranges, they are so completely different that they can't be compared. `=` assigns a reference, that's it. Clone creates a completely new object, one whose state should be the same as the cloned object, but again these two things are very very different.

Comment: It would help if you could provide sample code so that we could refer to it - showing code is better than describing it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll make my comment an answer:

Your question is comparing apples to oranges, they are so completely different that they can't be compared. `=` assigns a reference, that's it. Clone creates a completely **new object**, one whose **state** should be the same as the cloned object, but again it is a completely different object/reference.  As an aside, there are deep and shallow clones, and so the composite fields of shallow copied clones may be identical, but that's the subject of another question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use =, you copy the reference of the object (in memory). When using .clone(), you create a new object.